# Is there such a thing as an omnibus confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval

One sample test statistics (i.e. for null hypotheses about the relationship between a population quantity and some constant term) can be inverted straightforwardly to produce a confidence interval for that relationship.

Two sample test statistics (i.e. for null hypotheses about the relationship between two population quantities) can be inverted straightforwardly to produce a confidence interval for that relationship.

**Is there a way (even if not straightforward) to produce an omnibus confidence interval corresponding to an 'inversion' of an omnibus test (e.g., for null hypotheses about the simultaneous relationship between more than two population quantities)?**

This is a question about frequentist inference.

I am aware that omnibus tests can be applied to exactly two groups, but since these are typically equivalent to the two sample test, I want to stress more than two groups in my question.

Aside: Oh how interesting, we do not have an [omnibus](/questions/tagged/omnibus) tag!

Comment: Are you not able to create the tag for some reason? I see over 500 questions/answers with the use of "omnibus" - probably not all in the *true* sense.

Comment: @AdamO Oh, I **can** create it, but classess start Wednesday, and I am still finishing preparation up. :D

Answer (score 1):

This could be a very interesting question, but not simple to convert into something meaningful that can be explained to someone else.

Yes, you can always invert a test to find an interval, but what are you finding the interval for? can you understand what the interval means? can you explain the interval to someone else?

For example, one-way analysis of variance, the F-test could be inverted to give a confidence interval on the variances of the group means, but what does that tell us?  You could probably use some inequality theorem (sorry, long time since I have been in a theory class, so I remember there were a bunch of inequality theorems, but not their names or what each says) that could be used to show that since the maximum likely value (upper limit of CI) of the variance among the means is $S$, that means the biggest difference between 2 of the means is at most some value.  That may be interesting, but is it interesting enough for the extra work above and beyond what we learn from looking at Tukey pairwise interval?  And what would the lower limit on the variance among the means tell us?  That there is at least some amount of variance, but we can get that with 2 of the (at least 3) means still being equal to each other.

Remember that inverting the test to get an interval depends on additional assumptions.  For example to get a confidence interval for standard non parametric tests like the Wilcoxon/Mann-Whitney test we assume that one of the distributions is just the other distribution shifted by a constant (this assumption is not needed for the test).  But what if I believe that the truth is that one of my distributions is a scaled version of the other instead of a shifted distribution? then the standard CI method is incorrect (but in that case I can take the logs of my data, compute the CI since the scaling has turned into shifting, then exponentiate back to a CI on the scale).

When looking at 1 distribution/population or comparing 2 distributions/populations, then a simple shifting makes sense, can be interpreted, and can be explained (to some degree, most explanations I've seen on the CI for a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test rely heavily on the shift assumption (and sometimes on a symmetry assumption) without mentioning that condition/assumption).  But when we move to 3 or more groups, a simple shift in one group is not sufficient, we could look at shifts in $n-1$ groups, but that moves us from a Confidence Interval to a Confidence Region, which can be harder to visualize, interpret, and explain.

Comment: Greg there's a lot to chew on in your answer. However, I feel my question *does* imply a meaningful confidence interval: one which, were it not to span the value 0 (or whatever value would correspond to 'no effect'), would imply rejection of the corresponding omnibus null hypothesis.

Comment: @Alexis, If all you care about is if the "interval" (region) includes the value 0 (or whatever corresponds to 'no effect'), then you can just do the test and do not need to go to the trouble of creating a confidence region.  There are some cases (but some is not omnibus) where these types of regions can be helpful.  I have calculated and plotted 2 dimensional confidence regions and found insight there, but once the region is in 3 or more dimensions it is much harder to plot, interpret, and especially explain to someone else.

Comment: @Alexis,  If you really want a simple confidence interval, you could create the confidence region over multiple dimensions, then use the techniques of Linear Discriminant Analysis (comparing to your null point) to find a projection into 1 dimension that would give a confidence interval that you could check against 0 (or other null).  In some cases this could be quite insightful, but other cases would probably be very hard to interpret and not give any more insight than comparing the omnibus p-value to alpha.